# Ionic-Background to Foreground Process leads to crash the app in Android and iOS

Tags: android, ios, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

[image]I'm working on a hybrid mobile app. The app works fine in simulators and some devices. Especially, the app doesn't running properly in Samsung S-III(4.3) and iPhone 6(10.2.1) and 6+(10.2.3).

Unfortunately, the app is working good at Samsung Note-II(4.3) and iPhone 5s(10.2.1).

The app is crashed while launching the app from background mode to foreground. The Sessions are also stored. It is working weirdly for those particular devices.

Can anyone please clarify this issue?

Comment: Can you post error logs of crashes?

Comment: I didn't get any crash logs... It always navigates to login screen while launching the minimized the app.

Comment: you will see the crash of you connect your device to your system (with usb cable) and use android logcat or android monitor

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
<ion-scroll overflow-scroll="true" has-bouncing="false" lazy-scroll>
     //code goes here
</ion-scroll>
```

instead of `<ion-content>`

and use this in app.js

```
.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $ionicConfigProvider) {
            $ionicConfigProvider.views.swipeBackEnabled(false);
})
```